# Xamarin.Forms.WPF XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/wpf) Tutorial to include a WPF Project into my Xamarin.Forms solution. After going through all steps and comparing equality, the App starts, but immediatly runs into an exception.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Zeilennummer "7" und Zeilenposition "9" von "Durch den Aufruf des Konstruktors für Typ "Cheetah.Forms.WPF.MainWindow", der den angegebenen Bindungseinschränkungen entspricht, wurde eine Ausnahme ausgelöst.".
```

Here's my Xaml-file

```
<wpf:FormsApplicationPage x:Class="Cheetah.Forms.WPF.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                      xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF"
                      mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
</wpf:FormsApplicationPage>
```

And here is the Code-behind:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF;

namespace Cheetah.Forms.WPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : FormsApplicationPage
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new Cheetah.Forms.App());
        }
    }
}
```

I can'tfind out, what I am missing or doing wrong, so could that be a bug?

Comment: Can you share your xaml ? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure, I added the xaml and the code-behind

Comment: Is this the xaml complete content ?

Comment: From within the WPF project, yes.. But as I read, there should not be anything inside here

Comment: Maybe the information from the `InnerException` could lead us to your problem, what is stated there?

Comment: Is it possible that 'new Cheetah.Forms.App()' inside the MainWindow constructor is throwing some exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking "Only my Code" under Tools -> Options -> Debugging, I saw what was throwing the exception: I had to import all Nugets which are referenced from my Forms project. After I did this, the App starts as expected!